How to push an element into a vector by using a shared pointer to that vector
Probably a beginner question... but I have no clue on how to do a pushback in this case.
I have a struct circle:
struct circle
{
    std::string name;
    int PosX;
    int SpeedX;
    int PosY;
    int SpeedY;
    int ColorR;
    int ColorG;
    int ColorB;
    int Radius;
};

And I have a string array of an unknown number of lines with objects like
Circle cBlue 200 200 0.02 0.04 0 0 255 100

in a function having a shared pointer to a vector of circles, I want this circle to be pushed back into the vector.
void FindCircles(std::shared_ptr<DynamicArray<std::string>> LocalStringArray, std::shared_ptr<std::vector<circle>> MyCircles)
{
    // iterate over the array of strings 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < LocalStringArray->getSize() + 1; i++)
    {
        std::string ConfigElement = LocalStringArray->get(i);
//split the string into separate substrings
        std::vector<std::string> result = splitString(ConfigElement, ' ');

        // when the line is a circle
        if (result[0] == "Circle")
        {
            circle Circle1;
            Circle1.name   = result[1];
            Circle1.PosX   = std::stoi (result[2]);
            Circle1.SpeedX = std::stof (result[4]);
            Circle1.PosY   = std::stoi (result[3]);
            Circle1.SpeedY = std::stof (result[5]);
            Circle1.ColorR = std::stoi (result[6]);
            Circle1.ColorG = std::stoi (result[7]);
            Circle1.ColorB = std::stoi (result[8]);
            Circle1.Radius = std::stoi (result[9]);
            //pushback into Mycircles
        }
    }
}

Any advice on how to push back?
I tried to dereference the shared pointer but cannot find a useful member function.

sometimes things are easy ... but you just need to see it
MyCircles->push_back(Circle1);

in my stringarray there are 3 circles and the pushback does push 3 circles back into the MyCircles vector whish stays alive outside the function itself
sometimes a night of sleep does the trick
//find circles and copy them in circle array
void FindCircles(std::shared_ptr<DynamicArray<std::string>> LocalStringArray, std::shared_ptr<std::vector<circle>> MyCircles)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < LocalStringArray->getSize() + 1; i++)
    {
        std::string ConfigElement = LocalStringArray->get(i);
        std::vector<std::string> result = splitString(ConfigElement, ' ');

 
        if (result[0] == "Circle")
        {
            circle Circle1;
            Circle1.name   = result[1];
            Circle1.PosX   = std::stoi (result[2]);
            Circle1.SpeedX = std::stof (result[4]);
            Circle1.PosY   = std::stoi (result[3]);
            Circle1.SpeedY = std::stof (result[5]);
            Circle1.ColorR = std::stoi (result[6]);
            Circle1.ColorG = std::stoi (result[7]);
            Circle1.ColorB = std::stoi (result[8]);
            Circle1.Radius = std::stoi (result[9]);
        
            MyCircles->push_back(Circle1);
        }


    }
}

